# How do i ensure that data(str) received from body in fastapi is not empty

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```
id:str,
data: str = Body(...,embed=true,min_length=1)
```

I have tried to use **min length** but i would like to know if there is any other to ensure that received data from body is not empty.

Comment: That sounds like a fine solution, you can also use Pydantic's `constr` to indicate that something is a constrained string. It's also common to use a validator to convert empty strings into `None` if that the behavior you're really looking for, and then letting the regular required/optional validation handle it.

Comment: How does it work can you explain in the above case  ```id:str,
data: str = Body(...,embed=true,constr(min_length>0))``` ?

Comment: You'd use it in your schema (i.e. your request model), not usually in the view decorator. `class MyModel: data: constr(min_length=1)` https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types